# Is this an equivalence relation (reflexivity, symmetry, transitivity)

Tags: complex-analysis, equivalence-relations

Let $\theta(s):\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a well defined function. I define the following relation in $\mathbb{C}$.

$\forall s,q \in \mathbb{C}: s\mathbin{R}q\iff\theta(s)\ne 0 \pmod {2\pi}$  (and)

$\theta(q)\ne 0 \pmod {2\pi}$

The function $\pmod {2\pi}$ is the addition $\pmod {2\pi}$

My question: Is this an equivalence relation (reflexivity, symmetry, transitivity)?

The formula of $\theta(s)$ is not important for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relation is
$$sRq\iff \theta(s)\not \equiv 0\text{ and }\theta(q)\not \equiv 0 \mod 2\pi$$
for $s,q\in \mathbb{C}$.

For symmetry:
$$sRq\iff \theta(s)\not \equiv 0\text{ and }\theta(q)\not \equiv 0 \mod 2\pi \iff qRs$$

For transitivity:
$$sRq\text{ and }qRp\iff \theta(s)\not \equiv 0\text{ and }\theta(q)\not \equiv 0\text{ and }\theta(p)\not \equiv 0 \mod 2\pi\implies sRp$$
Reflexitivity is:
$$sRs\iff \theta(s)\not \equiv 0\mod 2\pi$$
That clearly depends on your choice of $\theta$. Therefore, $R$ is an equivalence relation iff $$\theta(\mathbb{C})\cap \left\{2k\pi:k\in \mathbb{Z}\right\}=\emptyset$$

Comment: Yes, I must define the relation in the set $Ω={s∈ℂ:θ(s)≠0}$

Comment: @user53124 $\theta (s)\not\equiv 0\mod 2\pi$

Comment: Yes and thank you.

Comment: @user53124 Happy to help

Comment: Of course, if that condition holds for $\theta$, then **every** pair of points is equivalent, so the relation is somewhat meaningless.

Comment: @copper.hat So you other have a meaningless equivalence relation or no equivalence relation at all

Comment: Yes; that is a meaningful statement!

Comment: It is not an equivalence relation if there exists a point in $\mathbb{C}$ for which any property fails. There exists infinitely many points q in $\mathbb{C}$  for which $\theta(q) \equiv 0 \pmod {2\pi}$, and for each of these, reflexivity fails. Hence, as defined (an equivalence relation holding $\forall q \in \mathbb{C})$, it is not an equivalence relation, as copper.hat makes clear. One cannot arbitrarily exclude points from the set on which the relation is defined, unless that was the point of the exercise: "Define a set such that the relation is an equivalence relation."

Answer (score 3):

It is not an equivalence relation if there exists $x$ such that $\theta(x) = 0 \mod 2\pi $.

You need reflexivity, so if $x$ satisfies $\theta(x) = 0 \mod 2\pi $, then you do **not** have $x R x$, hence it is not an equivalence relation.